# GCP mount 2 secrets in one directory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

I'm trying to mount 2 secrets in one directory on Cloud run.
GCP is showing an error as the mounting path is the same even though the filenames are different, I think maybe there's a way around this[image]

Comment: It's normal, you don't mount a file, but a path to the Container runtime. The directory path must be unique.

Comment: yep that's what i finally did, it's just that we have other env where we're putting these secrets in the same directory that's why i wanted to keep the same structure, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well according to the documentation, it's part of the product limitation.

Cloud Run does not allow you to mount multiple secrets at the same path because two volume mounts cannot be mounted at the same location.

You may want to check the documentation for more details.[1]

[1]

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/services/secrets#disallowed_paths_and_limitations